# Ansible ec2_vpc_route_table playbook error was: 'dict object' has no attribute subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

I have a previously working piece of Ansible that I've inherited for a previous contractor, and I'm getting an error message that doesn't lead me in the right direction. I have tried searching for a few days now, with no joy, and my colleagues can't figure it out either.

The Ansible in question is :-

```
- name: Routes | Set up NAT-protected route table
  ec2_vpc_route_table:
    vpc_id: "{{ ec2_vpc_net_reg.vpc.id }}"
    region: "{{ vpc_region }}"
    tags:
      Name: "Internal {{ item.subnet_id }}"
    subnets:
      - "{{ az_to_private_sub[public_subnets_to_az[item.subnet_id]] }}"
      - "{{ az_to_private_data_sub[public_subnets_to_az[item.subnet_id]] }}"
    routes:
      - dest: 0.0.0.0/0
        gateway_id: "{{ item.nat_gateway_id }}"
  loop: "{{ existing_nat_gateways.result|flatten(levels=1) }}"
  #with_items: "{{ existing_nat_gateways.result }}"
  register: nat_route_table
  retry: 2
  delay: 10
```

And the error message is :-

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute u'subnet-0facefaceface9'\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/cup/core-kubernetes-linux/ansible/roles/aws_vpc/tasks/routes.yml': line 62, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: Routes | Set up NAT-protected route table\n  ^ here\n"}
```

I have tried adding extra debug, for az_to_private_sub and public_subnet_to_az, and these look OK. I've tried reading the [docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#using-register-with-a-loop)

Can anyone suggest where I should look next?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After speaking to a different colleague, they pointed out that the version which works uses Ansible 2.5.5 and I was trying with 2.5.1 also the boto python libraries need to be using the correct version.